# <setBody>: how to encode \n?

Tags: escaping, apache-camel

imagine you would like to use the character sequence `\n` in a body of a message in apache-camel... 
I guess the easiest way would look like this:

```
<setBody>
  <simple>one line\nsecond line</simple>
</setBody>
```

unfortunately, the `\n` will be replaced with a line break. And escaping (`\\n`) seems not to work within the `<simple>` Tag...

Any idea how to solve this?

PS: I can't use the Java-DSL and also would like to avoid additional dependencies like `camel-groovy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution - a velocity template fits my needs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a constant body, you can use the `constant` language, with doesn't need to escape \n :

```
<setBody>
  <constant>one line\nsecond line</constant>
</setBody>
```

I am probably wrong, but I don't think it's possible today (v2.16.2) to quote a backslash in the simple language, in order to do what you want. If I look at the sources of `org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleTokenizer`, the `\\` is not handled as a special character. There is maybe some workaround, but it should be easy to create an issue // send a PR with this function.

Comment: I guess I can mix constant and simple, can't I? I'll try some thing like `<simple>foo</simple><constant>\n</constant><simple>bar</simple>`...

Comment: No, you can't, but you can create your own producer//language to do what you want

Comment: yeah, but that's not the goal of using camel :-(

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the camel sources for [Simple](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/cc9924f41965885af25027fc053adaf21f15b5b4/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/language/simple/SimpleLanguage.java) language. There is protected `allowEscape = true`, but no interface to set it. Of course you can inherit from it, and create your own `Simple` language, overriding this field.

From [SimpleTokenizer](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/cc9924f41965885af25027fc053adaf21f15b5b4/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/language/simple/SimpleTokenizer.java#L176) you can see, there is no way how to construct `\n` string, using current implementation.

Comment: thanx for your help - I found a solution (seem my answer)